# pycharm analysis complete. One typo found. Where is it?

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I use Pycharm 2016.1.4 (latest version at the moment) and it has a small box on the right top corner of the window (a checkbox if everything is correct).

[image]

When you click on it, it tells you some information about warnings/errors/typos.

Now that I understood that I have some problems, I would try to fix them. It is easy to see where errors and warnings are (their lines are highlighted on the right side of the scroll). But how can I quickly (without looking through whole text for a curly underline) identify positions of the typos?

Comment: F2/Shift+F2? Doesn't it work?

Comment: @greenshade thank you for a suggestion, but no. If it is relevant, I am on mac.

Comment: fn+shift+f2 takes me to the line with errors or typos on mac

Answer (score 18, accepted):

PyCharm tells you the type of the problem and it's location by tiny lines on the scroll bar of that file. Different colours mean different types of errors.

Red lines are breaking errors, yellow ones are suggestions. You can click on those little lines to be taken to the correct place.

This does not show the location of typos, that is true. But I found a workaround by going **Preferences -> Inspections** and turning the **Spelling -> Typo** severity to **Weak warning** in which case typos are properly displayed and you can use hotkeys for **Next highlighted error** and **Previous highlighted error** which are shown in your **Preferences -> Keymap** panel. For me, those are **F2** and **Shift + F2**, so I have to use **Fn + F2** or **Fn + Shift + F2** because I'm on a Macbook.

But I most often use the **Code -> Inspect code** option, because this searches your whole Project/Module for errors, warnings and even typos and shows them in a really convenient way in a different panel, where you can also click on the errors to be taken to the correct place. Also it shows the problem synopsis and a possible resolution.

Comment: Inspect code does show the location of typos, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the color for typos by searching for "typo" in the Settings dialog box. (For my version, it is in Editor / Color Scheme / General, within the "Errors and Warnings" group. Changing how typos are displayed helps you to locate them without changing their warning level or similar.

Comment: Note that if you also follow Eilyre's solution and change the typo severity to Weak warning this will NOT work! And this is not obvious, since typos will still get the default wavy formatting, while also being flagged as warnings.